# Return rows based off the most recent increase in value from other columns python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy, dataframe

The title of this question is a little confusing to write out succinctly.

I have `pandas` `df` that contains `integers` and a relevant `key` `Column`. When a value is in the `key` `Column` is present I want to return the most recent increase in `integers` from the other `Columns`.

For the `df` below, the `key` `Column` is `[Area]`. When `X` is in `[Area]`, I want to find the most recent increase is integers from `Columns` `['ST_A','PG_A','ST_B','PG_B']`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'ST_A' : [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],                 
    'PG_A' : [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],                 
    'ST_B' : [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],  
    'PG_B' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],   
    'Area' : ['','','X','','X','','','','X'],                 
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Output:

```
   ST_A  PG_A  ST_B  PG_B Area
0     0     0     0     0     
1     0     0     1     0     
2     0     0     1     0    X
3     0     1     1     0     
4     0     1     1     0    X
5     1     1     1     0     
6     1     2     1     0     
7     1     2     1     1     
8     1     2     1     1    X
```

I tried to use `df = df.loc[(df['Area'] == 'X')]` but this returns the `rows` where `X` is situated. I need something that uses `X` to return the most recent row where there was an increase in `Columns ['ST_A','PG_A','ST_B','PG_B']`.

I have also tried:

```
cols = ['ST_A','PG_A','ST_B','PG_B']
df[cols] = df[cols].diff()
df = df.fillna(0.)
df = df.loc[(df[cols] == 1).any(axis=1)]
```

This returns *all* `rows` where there was an increase in `Columns ['ST_A','PG_A','ST_B','PG_B']`. Not the most recent increase before `X` in `['Area']`.

Intended Output:

```
   ST_A  PG_A  ST_B  PG_B Area
1     0     0     1     0     
3     0     1     1     0     
7     1     2     1     1
```

Does this question make sense or do I need to simplify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use NumPy here via [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

increases = np.where(df.iloc[:, :-1].diff().gt(0).max(1))[0]
marks = np.where(df['Area'].eq('X'))[0]

idx = increases[np.searchsorted(increases, marks) - 1]

res = df.iloc[idx]

print(res)

   ST_A  PG_A  ST_B  PG_B Area
1     0     0     1     0     
3     0     1     1     0     
7     1     2     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient tho, but works, so big chunk of code which is kinda slow:

```
indexes=np.where(df['Area']=='X')[0].tolist()
indexes2=list(map((1).__add__,np.where(df[df.columns[:-1]].sum(axis=1) < df[df.columns[:-1]].shift(-1).sum(axis=1).sort_index())[0].tolist()))
l=[]
for i in indexes:
   if min(indexes2,key=lambda x: abs(x-i)) in l:
      l.append(min(indexes2,key=lambda x: abs(x-i))-2)
   else:
      l.append(min(indexes2,key=lambda x: abs(x-i)))
print(df.iloc[l].sort_index())
```

Output:

```
  Area  PG_A  PG_B  ST_A  ST_B
1          0     0     0     1
3          1     0     0     1
7          2     1     1     1
```